Desktop crash - gnome-flashback - 24.04
Lenovo T14S with intel CPU is the hardware and Ubuntu 24.04.01 was installed and on top, Regolith.
Currently I cannot leave the laptop unattended as it will crash the desktop after a period of idle time.
If I check dmesg, I have the following errors
...
gnome-flashback[3959]: segfault at 50 ip 00007aa758358203 sp 00007fff816357d0 error 4 in libgtk-3.so.0.2409.32[7aa758083000+3ae000] likely on CPU 9 (core 5, socket 0)
...
gnome-flashback[65370]: segfault at 5f0e0007be4c ip 00007b343ffa08fb sp 00007fff9ef85780 error 4 in libX11.so.6.4.0[7b343ff82000+90000] likely on CPU 2 (core 12, socket 0)
...

Can someone help me figure out more information and maybe a way to solve it?

Report bug? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs
